# Javascript Function that sorts nested array using splice

Tags: javascript

I want to sort a nested array using splice that looks like this

```js
[ [ 'Ruby', 65 ], [ 'Python', 90 ] , ['Javascript', 10]]
```

based on the values of the inner arrays in descending order.

expected output:

```js
[[ 'Python', 90 ] , ['Ruby', 65], ['Javascript',10]]
```

My try:

```js
function ordarray (para){

  let results=para

  for (let j=0; j<results.length; j++){
    if (results[j][1] < results[j+1][1]) {
      results.splice(results[j], 0, results[j+1])
    }
  }

  return results
}
```

When invoked, I get the error message "Cannot read property '1' of undefined"

Thanks for reading!

Comment: duplicate but you can try this :`array.sort((a,b)=>b[1]-a[1])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid modifying the array when it is under iteration. This line `results[j+1][1]` will give rise to issue since it will try to looking for the element in the index which is undefined

```js
let arr = [
  ['Ruby', 65],
  ['Python', 90],
  ['Javascript', 10]
];

function ordarray(para) {
  return para.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])
}

console.log(ordarray(arr))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```js
var data = [ [ 'Ruby', 65 ], [ 'Python', 90 ] , ['Javascript', 10]];
data.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);
console.log(data);
```